# Cannot connect to SQL Server express 2012 from Eclipse and JDBC

Tags: java, sql-server, eclipse, jdbc

I try connect to SQL Server express 2012 which is installed on my own machine.
In properties of Ms SQL name is: `BGHFVUI535V2\SQLEXPRESS`

In Java I have:

```
try
{
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

    databaseName = "dblfa1;integratedSecurity=true";
    String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://BGHFVUI535V2\SQLEXPRESS;user=mysa;password=mypsw;databaseName=dbmy";
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And I get this Exception:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection to the host BGHFVUI535V2, named instance sqlexpress failed. Error: "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out". Verify the server and instance names and check that no firewall is blocking UDP traffic to port 1434.  For SQL Server 2005 or later, verify that the SQL Server Browser Service is running on the host.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.getInstancePort(SQLServerConnection.java:3589)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.primaryPermissionCheck(SQLServerConnection.java:1225)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:972)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:827)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at ClassStart.main(ClassStart.java:34)
```

In c# I have connectionstring :

```
string connectionString = "Server=BGHFVUI535V2\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=dbmy;User Id=mysa;Password=mypsw;";
```

and it works.

Comment: On Java connection you have **User** instead of **User Id**

Comment: I changed to User Id=mysa but result is the same

Comment: From the error message: "verify that the SQL Server Browser Service is running on the host."

Comment: It is runngin because from c# I can connect to database without any problem. TCP protocol is enabled too

Comment: The fact that you can connect from C# does *not* guarantee that the SQL Server Browser service is running. C# can connect to a local SQL Server instance when the SQL Server Browser service is stopped. You will actually have to launch the SQL Server Configuration Manager and check the "SQL Server Services" tab to see if the Browser service is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;user=MyUserName;password=*****;";
```

From MSDN site. [Link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms378428(v=sql.110).aspx)

Comment: Firewall is disabled. I still getting this same error. From c# it works.